# Need help diagnosing cudaMemcpyToSymbol error

Tags: cuda, constants, gpu

I'm writing a code and using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` to copy some `cudaPitchedPtrs` to the (multiple per process) GPU devices so that I have convenient access to some host-copied memory. However, I have found a very strange bug (I hesitate to call it that, but I do not have another explanation) that I do not know how to work around effectively. Here's the part of my code responsible:

So from main() in main.c I call init_gpu() in gpu_kernels.cu (init_gpu has the usual `extern "C"` framework, but I removed this and it did not affect the problem below). gpu_utilities.cu is the only file to include gpu_decs.h  (I inline all my CUDA source into gpu_kernels.cu).

Now, here's a segment of gpu_decs.h:

```
  __constant__ struct cudaPitchedPtr rad_gpu;

  //__constant__ struct cudaPitchedPtr test_pptr;
```

When this second line is commented out, the following cudaMemcpyToSymbol operation fails with error code 11:

```
cudaErrorCheck(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(rad_gpu, 
    &((*gpu_rad_parms)[n].dstPtr), sizeof(struct cudaPitchedPtr),
    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice), "init_gpu - rad_gpu - symbol");
```

However, when I uncomment test_pptr (which is never defined or used anywhere in my code) this line does not throw an error. The type of test_pptr does not seem to matter, as long as it is larger than a char, I think (this may not be true; I have not completely characterized the problem).

Of possible interest is that without this line rad_gpu is the last __constant__ declaration in gpu_decs.h. However, this error still makes no sense to me. Has anyone seen or heard tales of this problem before, and have a reliable way to resolve it? I am uncomfortable with leaving test_pptr declared and considering the issue resolved.

Comment: Try replacing the first argument of the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call with a string containing the symbol name (so `cudaMemcpyToSymbol("rad_gpu",......)`)

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't have any effect in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that there is type size mismatch: cudaPitchedPtr has several fields of type size_t. So if on your host side sizeof(size_t) is 8 bytes while on the device this is 4 bytes you might get problems. This can also explain why defining another pitchedPtr solves the problem since more memory is allocated.

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess cudaPitchedPtrs should always be passed as kernel arguments.